# How to remove special character for a single string with commas in it?

Tags: python, pandas, python-re

I need to remove a special character set (eg (x)) for a single string with commas in it.

Here is an example of the objective:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| Brash (7), Confident (7), Street-Smart (6), Calm/Peaceful(5) | Brash, Confident, Street-Smart, Calm/Peaceful |

I've tried using the following codes:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].fillna('').astype(str).str.replace(r'[^A-Za-z ]', '', regex=True)
df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace(r" \(.*\)","")
```

But I'm only able to keep the first element or remove all the special characters, and I just need to remove the pattern (x)

Comment: your code ```df['col'] = df['col2'].str.replace(r" \(.*\)","")``` is working for me just fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "element of a row"? Do you have `Brash (7), Confident (7), Street-Smart (6), Calm/Peaceful(5)` in a *single cell*? Is that a single string with commas in it, or a list of strings, or what?

Comment: Use `r" \(.*?\)"` as regex

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, is a single string with commas in it. Sorry for the dubious expression

Comment: Aha. Then the problem is simply that e.g. `\(.*\)` matches `(7), Confident (7), Street-Smart (6), Calm/Peaceful(5)` - *as much as possible* that satisfies the condition. See the linked duplicate for details. The answer you accepted works around the problem by only accepting digits within the parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['col'].str.replace(r'\((\d+).*?\)', '', regex=True)
```